# How can I get the source line number for veracode reports in jar build by Maven

Tags: java, veracode

We are running static analysis on the project to find the bugs in the code. In the process we are uploading the ear files, which contains the jar files that are build by maven. In the static analysis we are unable to locate the issue in the jar as it is always point to the starting line i.e, line no 1.

```
com/.../util/testconstanst.java 1
```

can anyone tell, how to turn on debug mode in the maven while building the jar .

Comment: how are you doing it now? You're not telling anything about how you try to retrieve the source code line number.

Comment: Which tool used for static analysis?

Comment: maybe you're thinking about C or similar - javac compiles with line numbers in .class files by default, so the information is already there.

Comment: @eis unfortunately it is working for the ear and war files using maven only without turning on the debug mode. I am working on Java only

Comment: @SergeyProkofiev we are using veracode source code analzyer.

Comment: ok, so veracode has problems opening inner .jar files. That's a problem of veracode.

Comment: @eis that issue cant be solved...??

Comment: @ramesh027 that's something you might want to check from Veracode (support@veracode.com). However, as a workaround aren't you able to just send .ears and .jars separately?